# how to combine free floating meshes

Tags: mesh

So I have made 4 box objects and after moving them to make a perfectly spaced grid I then combined them to make one object.

They all share the same edges (I think) or at least they are in the same places. O_o

How would I combine all of these boxes so that they maintain their individual faces but are connected at the edges?

Comment: In Edit Mode select all ('A'), press 'W > Remove Doubles'.

Comment: make that an answer so I can mark is as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edit Mode select all <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.

Comment: ty so much :) I love simple answers

Comment: Good question = simple answer ;)

Comment: @puppy333 do note that you will still have internal faces. that is something you may not want (depending on what you are doing with the model).

Comment: internal faces are better then free floating parts and pieces :P